# how many parameters can be estimated

Tags: regression-strategies

First edition, Prof Harrell's REGRESSION MODELING STRATEGIES, section 8.2, "How many parameters can be estimated?", page 150, quoting "If predicting survival time were of major interest, we could develop a reliable model if no more than about 354/15 = 24 parameters were *examined* in modeling."

QUESTION: Where does the "15" come from? Is there a reference in the survival analysis section of the text (Chapter 16) which describes?

Note: Apologies if this is explained in the second edition of the text. I have just ordered a copy.

Answer (score 5):

It comes from earlier in the book. Section 4.4: Sample Size, Overfitting, and Limits on Number of Predictors (p. 72 in the 2nd Edition; the simulation study that came to this rule-of-thumb is discussed in the subsequent two pages.):
[image]