# Why it might be bad to have too many feature levels

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, many-categories, feature-engineering

I am aware that a feature with *too many* levels might be bad for a number of algorithms (e.g. Logistic Regression).

A typical approach to fix this would be to group the categories with a frequency lower than a predefined threshold in a single category (e.g. "Other").

But, technically speaking, why is having too many levels on a feature exactly bad? Are there any algorithms for which this fix isn't needed, i.e. that address this issue internally?

Comment: Your 1st paragraph & the 1st sentence of your 3rd paragraph seem inconsistent with each other. Moreover, I don't know that logistic regression is in any way special WRT this issue.

Comment: As a general matter, it's hard to estimate effect sizes when you don't have much data. Suppose you're randomly sampling 5000 people from all of the USA. Many of America's ~3000 counties will have 0 or 1 people in your sample, purely due to the vagaries of random sampling. It will be challenging to say anything definitive about whatever phenomenon you're studying at the county level. But aggregating to the level of the 50 states might informative, and more precise, because you'll have more data about each state (but you won't easily make county-level inferences).

Comment: Aggregating to "other" category is not the only (or best) solution. In neural networks you can use entity embeddings. General solution that works well is to use hashing trick.

Comment: @gung Why do you think so? In the 1st paragraph im stating that too many levels might be bad, while on the 3rd one I'm asking what are the reasons for being bad.

Comment: "I am aware that a feature with too many levels might be bad" & "But, technically speaking, why is having too many levels on a feature exactly bad?" is at least somewhat inconsistent. If what you're trying to get at is, 'I have been told that having too many levels is bad, but I don't understand why', some other phrasing might make it easier for people to figure out where you are.

Comment: Well, each new feature level increases the number of parameters with 1, and too many parameters is difficult.  You can find interesting ideas in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels

Answer (score 2):

Each new feature level increases the number of parameters by 1, and too many parameters makes estimation difficult. Sometimes it is said that in linear regression, you should have ten observations for each parameter. See [how many parameters can be estimated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279337/how-many-parameters-can-be-estimated)  and more details in the book there cited.

You propose *to group the categories with a frequency lower than a predefined threshold in a single category (e.g. "Other")*. That can be a bad approach, just because two levels have few observations doesn't mean they have the same effect on the response. Some other method is called for, and there are good suggestions here:  [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels).  Also search for the [many-categories](/questions/tagged/many-categories) tag.